# Uninstall Pop!_OS?

Tags: boot, windows, uefi, pop-os

Ok. So I'm not a linux user generally, but I haven't had a good experience with Windows so I decided to switch over and install Pop_OS. It was really good for a time, but I eventually realized I couldn't install a lot of the software I need to use for my work (Unity/Unreal/DaVinci Resolve for example). I want to uninstall the OS and switch to Windows 11 but I can't because every time I try to get to the boot menu, dialogue pops up and says "encryption key?". Then when I enter it, it just goes straight back into Pop!_OS. Is there any way to wipe the ssd or to get the computer to run from a thumb drive (actually access the boot menu)?

Comment: This is really a question about your UEFI boot menu. You probably need to hit F12 or F10 on startup to avoid booting the default device, or change the boot order in your UEFI setup.

Answer (score 1):

Do you hit F2 to get into the BIOS?

From there you can change the boot order.

Maybe you have triggered a BitLocker recovery:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-recovery-guide-plan

Unfortunately I really can't help with this. Did you encrypt your HD when installing Pop OS?

If you have your Windows 11 key you can wipe the entire HD from a bootable USB and reinstall Windows 11 on it. Sometimes the Windows 11 key is printed on a physical label on your device (PC or Laptop?), sometimes it is stored in the device itself. So when you wipe the HD and install Windows 11 it should activate automatically.

I think you can't access the boot menu from a bootable device. But there might by a way to repair your boot order from the Windows 11 installer, by using the advanced startup order like you would from within Windows 11 on the HD.

Sorry to hear that Pop OS didn't work out for you!

Answer (score 0):

secure boot is blocking everything. if you log into your microcrap account and you can find your bit locker code to unlock the crap matched to that computer. normally you have to disable secure boot to install linux. at least in my amateur experince. good luck.